# OpenTok createSession

Tags: node.js, opentok

I am trying to create session using openTok Nodejs.
I don't get any error but the session isn't created.

```
var OpenTok = require('opentok'),
opentok = new OpenTok(vc_config.ot_api_key,  vc_config.ot_secret);

opentok.createSession({mediaMode:"routed"}, function(err, session) {
if (err) { return console.log(err); }
console.log(session);
this.session_id = session.sessionId;
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) issue, I solved this with:

```
       var opentok = new OpenTok(ot_api_key, ot_secret);

       await(opentok.createSession({mediaMode:"routed"}, function(error, session) {
       if (error) { return console.log(error); }
       return OtSessionDatum.findOne({ where: { id: modelId }}).then(function (ot_session_datum) {
         return ot_session_datum.update({session_id: session.sessionId,
                                         subscriber_token: session.generateToken({role: 'subscriber'}),
                                         publisher_token: session.generateToken({role: 'publisher'}),
                                         moderator_token: session.generateToken({role: 'moderator'}),
                                         watch_token: session.generateToken({role: 'moderator',data:'watch'})});

     }));
```